# Fighting for Father's Attention - Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> I love my father. I've been around him as long as I can remember. People often talk about us as being complementary, as if I were as great as he. I don't have much to offer, so I just show everyone how glorious he is.
>
> I have to show my father's glory to everyone because of my big sister. She is so controlling and makes me be around her all the time, like a slave. Now I can't be me without everyone seeing her first. She also has a lot more stuff than me, which makes her special. I give in to her demands, but still stay with our father. I can make do with my situation by showing how great Father is, but her intervention makes her seem like the successful daughter while I get tossed around. Now I admit this is mean, but I mess with my sister often, picking at her tears. Somehow, we all live on.

Who/What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The Moon

Explanation

> The Moon revolves around the Sun along with the Earth from time immemorial.
>  The Sun and the Moon are complementary.
>  The Moon shows the Sun's glory by reflecting its light.
>  The big sister is the Earth. As mentioned above, the Moon revolves around the Earth. The Earth controls the moon by its gravity.
>  Clearly Earth has life, rivers, valleys, volcanoes, etc. but moon doesn't.
>  Again Earth and Moon are in the Solar system and under the Sun's control.
>  The Moon causes intervention by resulting in rise and fall of tides (may be tears).
>  The Sun, the Moon and the Earth are all in the same solar system (living together).